# playing youtube videos in J2me Lwuit form

Tags: video, java-me, youtube, lwuit

In my project i need to show and play youtube videos in my j2me lwuit based form through RSS Feeds? i could not find any such example on internet? How can i show and play youtube videos on my J2me bases LWUIT Form?

Comment: As far as My knowledge in j2me,we cannot perform Http based Streaming in j2me,if you want to stream and play youtube videos,try to parse and get the RTSP link from your youtube URL,Because in java-me we can successfully stream and play RTSP Protocol based URL if you want, here i am providing the code to stream RTSP URL:[Click Here to go to the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897229/j2me-rtsp-video-streams-but-no-audio/12908234#12908234)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the only option that might possibly work for some cases would be to use `Display.getInstance().execute(url)` to open the youtube video itself.

Comment: it is successfully opening "http://www.youtube.com". but when i try to open a particular video it is failed to do so, for example i am unable to open "http://www.youtube.com/v/Q3dpUTJeFXA" through this code.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean on the device. Most devices will have a problem with playing youtube content.

Comment: yes like when i click on youtube video on Nokia Asha Device it plays that video in its native player. I also want to open that player and pass the video link to that player? How can i acheive this?