# J2ME RTSP Video Streams but no Audio

Tags: video, java-me, streaming, nokia, rtsp

I've followed Nokia's wiki about creating the video player with J2Me. Generally the code is like these

```
player = Manager.createPlayer("rtsp://v1.cache5.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQm8E_KpEOI9cxMYDSANFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYLm0hv_ig5HRTww=/0/0/0/video.3gp");               

                  //A player listener is needed so that we know, when the video has reached the END_OF_MEDIA position
            player.addPlayerListener(this);
            player.realize();
            player.prefetch();

          //The duration of the video
            duration = player.getDuration();

            //The video control instance is created and attached to this Canvas in Full SCreen mode
            vc = (VideoControl)player.getControl("VideoControl");

            voc = (VolumeControl)player.getControl("VolumeControl");
            voc.setLevel(100);
            voc.setMute(false);


            vc.initDisplayMode(VideoControl.USE_DIRECT_VIDEO, this);
            vc.setDisplaySize(240, 196);
            //vc.setDisplayFullScreen(true);

            vc.setVisible(true);





           // vc.setDisplayFullScreen(true);
            //next time the above operations will be skipped
            firstPlay = false;

          //A new thread handles the move of the cursor while the video progresses. 
            //The thread is distroyed when the video is stopped.
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
```

Currently I developed for Nokia Asha 311.  If I just open the rtsp address via browser the native video player will pop up and streams the video with the audio, and with this code the Video streams smoothly but no sound at all.

Did i do something wrong? Thanks for your help

Regards

Answer (score 0):

To stream an play youtube videos you can use the below Code:

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.microedition.media.*;
import javax.microedition.media.control.VideoControl;

public class RTSPFullScreen extends MIDlet implements CommandListener, PlayerListener {

    private Display d;
    private Player p;
    private Canvas c;
    private Command exitCommand = new Command("Exit", Command.EXIT, 1);
    VideoControl vc;

    public RTSPFullScreen() {

        d = Display.getDisplay(this);


    }

    public void startApp() {
        c = new Canvas() {

            protected void paint(Graphics g) {

                g.setColor(0, 0, 0);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());


            }
        };

        c.setFullScreenMode(true);
        c.addCommand(exitCommand);
        c.setCommandListener(this);
        d.setCurrent(c);




        try {
           p = Manager.createPlayer("rtsp://v1.cache5.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQm8E_KpEOI9cxMYDSANFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYLm0hv_ig5HRTww=/0/0/0/video.3gp");


            p.addPlayerListener(this);
            p.start();

            vc = (VideoControl) p.getControl("javax.microedition.media.control.VideoControl");
            vc.initDisplayMode(VideoControl.USE_DIRECT_VIDEO, c);



        } catch (Exception e) {
            showAlert("startApp: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void commandAction(Command c, Displayable s) {
        if (c == exitCommand) {
            destroyApp(false);
            notifyDestroyed();
        }
    }

    public void pauseApp() {
    }

    public void destroyApp(boolean uc) {
        if (p != null) {
            p.close();
        }
    }

    public void playerUpdate(Player player, java.lang.String event, java.lang.Object eventData) {
        if (player.getState() == Player.STARTED) {

            try {

                vc.setDisplayFullScreen(true);
                vc.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                showAlert("playerUpdate: " + e.toString());
            }
        }

    }

    public void showAlert(String aAlertText) {
        Alert alert = new Alert("Alert", aAlertText, null, AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTimeout(10000);
        d.setCurrent(alert);
    }
}
```